# lost everything after update please help

Tags: xbox-360

ok I recently got internet and wanted to set it up on my xbox 360. I set up the internet and it imeditaly sent my console into an update. After the update was finished all my data on my concle dissappered. I do not have any live accounts on my 360 only offline and now all my accounts are gone as well as all data from over 50 games. Is there any way to reset my console and recover my data?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research and things do not look good.

Apparently, certain updates to the dashboard, particularly if you apply multiple major updates at once (such as in this case) can reformat or corrupt the hard drive.

Since you've never connected the console to the internet and I assume you never backed up the hard drive, the data won't be anywhere else. This means that even if Microsoft support cared (and I found multiple cases where they outright disconnected calls about this), they'd be unable to help.

There are two possible solutions I can find:

- Some people with this issue reported that disconnecting the hard drive and reattaching it worked and restored the data.
- You may have some luck with a professional data restoration service, though I can't confirm if this would work. It depends what's actually happened to the drive.